# "Missing value for primary key"

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I'd just migrated to Symfony 3.4 and had this kind of message :
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\Common\Proxy\Exception\OutOfBoundsException: "Missing value for primary key idBen on Lea\PrestaBundle\Entity\EgwContact" at /htdocs/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/Exception/OutOfBoundsException.php line 40

Thanks in advance for your help

Here is my entity code for egw_contact :

```
<?php

namespace Lea\PrestaBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * Lea\PrestaBundle\Entity\EgwContact
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="egw_contact")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Lea\PrestaBundle\Entity\EgwContactRepository")
 */
class EgwContact
{
    /**
     * @var integer $idBen
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_ben", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $idBen;

    /**
     * @var string $idOrganisation
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_organisation", type="string", length=64, nullable=true)
     */
    private $idOrganisation;

    /**
     * @var integer $idOwner
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_owner", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     */
    private $idOwner;

    /**
     * @var integer $dateCreation
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_creation", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     */
    private $dateCreation;

    /**
     * @var integer $idModifier
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_modifier", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     */
    private $idModifier;

    /**
     * @var integer $dateLastModified
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_last_modified", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     */
    private $dateLastModified;

    /**
     * @var string $catId
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cat_id", type="string", length=32, nullable=false)
     */
    private $catId;

    /**
     * @var string $civilite
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="civilite", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $civilite;

    /**
     * @var string $nomComplet
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom_complet", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $nomComplet;

    /**
     * @var string $nom
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @var string $prenom
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="prenom", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $prenom;

    /**
     * @var string $deuxiemePrenom
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="deuxieme_prenom", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $deuxiemePrenom;

    /**
     * @var string $nomJeuneFille
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom_jeune_fille", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $nomJeuneFille;


    /**
     * @var string $organisation
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="organisation", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $organisation;

    /**
     * @var string $fonction
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fonction", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $fonction;

    /**
     * @var string $service
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Service", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $service;

    /**
     * @var string $adresseLigne1
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="adresse_ligne_1", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $adresseLigne1;

    /**
     * @var string $adresseLigne2
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="adresse_ligne_2", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $adresseLigne2;

    /**
     * @var string $adresseLigne3
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="adresse_ligne_3", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $adresseLigne3;

    /**
     * @var string $ville
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ville", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $ville;

    /**
     * @var string $region
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="region", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $region;

    /**
     * @var string $cp
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cp", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $cp;

    /**
     * @var string $pays
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="pays", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $pays;

    /**
     * @var string $telPro1
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tel_pro_1", type="string", length=40, nullable=false)
     */
    private $telPro1;

    /**
     * @var string $telPro2
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tel_pro_2", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $telPro2;

    /**
     * @var string $telDomicile1
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tel_domicile_1", type="string", length=14, nullable=false)
     */
    private $telDomicile1;

    /**
     * @var string $telDomicile2
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tel_domicile_2", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $telDomicile2;

    /**
     * @var string $faxPro
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fax_pro", type="string", length=40, nullable=false)
     */
    private $faxPro;

    /**
     * @var string $faxPerso
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fax_perso", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $faxPerso;

    /**
     * @var string $portablePro
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="portable_pro", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $portablePro;

    /**
     * @var string $portablePerso
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="portable_perso", type="string", length=40, nullable=false)
     */
    private $portablePerso;

    /**
     * @var string $emailPro
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email_pro", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $emailPro;

    /**
     * @var string $emailPerso
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email_perso", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $emailPerso;

    /**
     * @var string $sitePerso
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="site_perso", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $sitePerso;

    /**
     * @var string $dateNaissance
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_naissance", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $dateNaissance;

    /**
     * @var string $lieuNaissance
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lieu_naissance", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $lieuNaissance;

    /**
     * @var string $paysNaissance
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="pays_naissance", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $paysNaissance;

    /**
     * @var string $nationalite
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nationalite", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $nationalite;

    /**
     * @var string $situationMaritale
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="situation_maritale", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $situationMaritale;

    /**
     * @var integer $enfantsACharge
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="enfants_a_charge", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $enfantsACharge;


    /**
     * @var integer $idSecu
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="numero_SS", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $idSecu;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EgwCategories", mappedBy="contactCategorie")
     */
    private $typeContact;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Relance", mappedBy="contact")
     *
     */
    protected $relances;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EgwProjet", mappedBy="contact")
     */
    protected $projets;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EgwPrestation", mappedBy="contact")
     */
    protected $prestations;

     /**
      * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EgwPrestation", mappedBy="contactP")
      */
    protected $prestationsP;


    /**
      * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EgwContactParcoursPro", mappedBy="parcoursProContact")
      */
    protected $contactParcoursPro;


     /**
      * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EgwContactFormation", mappedBy="formationContact")
      */
    protected $contactFormation;



    public function __construct()
    {
    $this->prestations = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->prestationsP = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->contactParcoursPro = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->contactFormation = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->typeContact = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->projets = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get idBen
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getIdBen()
    {
        return $this->idBen;
    }

    /**
     * Set idOrganisation
     *
     * @param string $idOrganisation
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setIdOrganisation($idOrganisation = null)
    {
        $this->idOrganisation = $idOrganisation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idOrganisation
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getIdOrganisation()
    {
        return $this->idOrganisation;
    }

    /**
     * Set idOwner
     *
     * @param integer $idOwner
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setIdOwner($idOwner)
    {
        $this->idOwner = $idOwner;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idOwner
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getIdOwner()
    {
        return $this->idOwner;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateCreation
     *
     * @param integer $dateCreation
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setDateCreation($dateCreation)
    {
        $this->dateCreation = $dateCreation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateCreation
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getDateCreation()
    {
        return $this->dateCreation;
    }

    /**
     * Set idModifier
     *
     * @param integer $idModifier
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setIdModifier($idModifier)
    {
        $this->idModifier = $idModifier;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idModifier
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getIdModifier()
    {
        return $this->idModifier;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateLastModified
     *
     * @param integer $dateLastModified
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setDateLastModified($dateLastModified)
    {
        $this->dateLastModified = $dateLastModified;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateLastModified
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getDateLastModified()
    {
        return $this->dateLastModified;
    }

    /**
     * Set catId
     *
     * @param string $catId
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setCatId($catId)
    {
        $this->catId = $catId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get catId
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCatId()
    {
        return $this->catId;
    }

    /**
     * Set civilite
     *
     * @param string $civilite
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setCivilite($civilite)
    {
        $this->civilite = $civilite;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get civilite
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCivilite()
    {
        return $this->civilite;
    }


    /**
     * Set nomComplet
     *
     * @param string $nomComplet
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setNomComplet($nomComplet)
    {
        $this->nomComplet = $nomComplet;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nomComplet
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNomComplet()
    {
        return $this->nomComplet;
    }

    /**
     * Set nom
     *
     * @param string $nom
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setNom($nom)
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nom
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNom()
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    /**
     * Set prenom
     *
     * @param string $prenom
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setPrenom($prenom)
    {
        $this->prenom = $prenom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get prenom
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPrenom()
    {
        return $this->prenom;
    }

    /**
     * Set deuxiemePrenom
     *
     * @param string $deuxiemePrenom
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setDeuxiemePrenom($deuxiemePrenom)
    {
        $this->deuxiemePrenom = $deuxiemePrenom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get deuxiemePrenom
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDeuxiemePrenom()
    {
        return $this->deuxiemePrenom;
    }

    /**
     * Set nomJeuneFille
     *
     * @param string $nomJeuneFille
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setNomJeuneFille($nomJeuneFille)
    {
        $this->nomJeuneFille = $nomJeuneFille;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nomJeuneFille
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNomJeuneFille()
    {
        return $this->nomJeuneFille;
    }

    /**
     * Set organisation
     *
     * @param string $organisation
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setOrganisation($organisation)
    {
        $this->organisation = $organisation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get organisation
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getOrganisation()
    {
        return $this->organisation;
    }

    /**
     * Set fonction
     *
     * @param string $fonction
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setFonction($fonction)
    {
        $this->fonction = $fonction;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fonction
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFonction()
    {
        return $this->fonction;
    }

    /**
     * Set service
     *
     * @param string $service
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setService($service)
    {
        $this->service = $service;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get service
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getService()
    {
        return $this->service;
    }

    /**
     * Set adresseLigne1
     *
     * @param string $adresseLigne1
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setAdresseLigne1($adresseLigne1)
    {
        $this->adresseLigne1 = $adresseLigne1;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get adresseLigne1
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAdresseLigne1()
    {
        return $this->adresseLigne1;
    }

    /**
     * Set adresseLigne2
     *
     * @param string $adresseLigne2
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setAdresseLigne2($adresseLigne2)
    {
        $this->adresseLigne2 = $adresseLigne2;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get adresseLigne2
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAdresseLigne2()
    {
        return $this->adresseLigne2;
    }

    /**
     * Set adresseLigne3
     *
     * @param string $adresseLigne3
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setAdresseLigne3($adresseLigne3)
    {
        $this->adresseLigne3 = $adresseLigne3;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get adresseLigne3
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAdresseLigne3()
    {
        return $this->adresseLigne3;
    }

    /**
     * Set ville
     *
     * @param string $ville
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setVille($ville)
    {
        $this->ville = $ville;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get ville
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getVille()
    {
        return $this->ville;
    }

    /**
     * Set region
     *
     * @param string $region
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setRegion($region)
    {
        $this->region = $region;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get region
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getRegion()
    {
        return $this->region;
    }

    /**
     * Set cp
     *
     * @param string $cp
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setCp($cp)
    {
        $this->cp = $cp;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get cp
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCp()
    {
        return $this->cp;
    }

    /**
     * Set pays
     *
     * @param string $pays
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setPays($pays)
    {
        $this->pays = $pays;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get pays
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPays()
    {
        return $this->pays;
    }

    /**
     * Set telPro1
     *
     * @param string $telPro1
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setTelPro1($telPro1)
    {
        $this->telPro1 = $telPro1;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get telPro1
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTelPro1()
    {
        return $this->telPro1;
    }

    /**
     * Set telPro2
     *
     * @param string $telPro2
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setTelPro2($telPro2)
    {
        $this->telPro2 = $telPro2;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get telPro2
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTelPro2()
    {
        return $this->telPro2;
    }

    /**
     * Set telDomicile1
     *
     * @param string $telDomicile1
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setTelDomicile1($telDomicile1)
    {
        $this->telDomicile1 = $telDomicile1;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get telDomicile1
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTelDomicile1()
    {
        return $this->telDomicile1;
    }

    /**
     * Set telDomicile2
     *
     * @param string $telDomicile2
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setTelDomicile2($telDomicile2)
    {
        $this->telDomicile2 = $telDomicile2;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get telDomicile2
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTelDomicile2()
    {
        return $this->telDomicile2;
    }

    /**
     * Set faxPro
     *
     * @param string $faxPro
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setFaxPro($faxPro)
    {
        $this->faxPro = $faxPro;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get faxPro
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFaxPro()
    {
        return $this->faxPro;
    }

    /**
     * Set faxPerso
     *
     * @param string $faxPerso
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setFaxPerso($faxPerso)
    {
        $this->faxPerso = $faxPerso;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get faxPerso
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFaxPerso()
    {
        return $this->faxPerso;
    }

    /**
     * Set portablePro
     *
     * @param string $portablePro
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setPortablePro($portablePro)
    {
        $this->portablePro = $portablePro;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get portablePro
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPortablePro()
    {
        return $this->portablePro;
    }

    /**
     * Set portablePerso
     *
     * @param string $portablePerso
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setPortablePerso($portablePerso)
    {
        $this->portablePerso = $portablePerso;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get portablePerso
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPortablePerso()
    {
        return $this->portablePerso;
    }

    /**
     * Set emailPro
     *
     * @param string $emailPro
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setEmailPro($emailPro)
    {
        $this->emailPro = $emailPro;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get emailPro
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEmailPro()
    {
        return $this->emailPro;
    }

    /**
     * Set emailPerso
     *
     * @param string $emailPerso
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setEmailPerso($emailPerso)
    {
        $this->emailPerso = $emailPerso;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get emailPerso
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEmailPerso()
    {
        return $this->emailPerso;
    }

    /**
     * Set sitePerso
     *
     * @param string $sitePerso
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setSitePerso($sitePerso)
    {
        $this->sitePerso = $sitePerso;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get sitePerso
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSitePerso()
    {
        return $this->sitePerso;
    }


    /**
     * Set dateNaissance
     *
     * @param string $dateNaissance
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setDateNaissance($dateNaissance)
    {
        $this->dateNaissance = $dateNaissance;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Get dateNaissance
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDateNaissance()
    {
        return $this->dateNaissance;
    }

    /**
     * Set lieuNaissance
     *
     * @param string $lieuNaissance
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setLieuNaissance($lieuNaissance)
    {
        $this->lieuNaissance = $lieuNaissance;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lieuNaissance
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLieuNaissance()
    {
        return $this->lieuNaissance;
    }

    /**
     * Set paysNaissance
     *
     * @param string $paysNaissance
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setPaysNaissance($paysNaissance)
    {
        $this->paysNaissance = $paysNaissance;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get paysNaissance
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPaysNaissance()
    {
        return $this->paysNaissance;
    }

    /**
     * Set nationalite
     *
     * @param string $nationalite
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setNationalite($nationalite)
    {
        $this->nationalite = $nationalite;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nationalite
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNationalite()
    {
        return $this->nationalite;
    }

    /**
     * Set situationMaritale
     *
     * @param string $situationMaritale
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setSituationMaritale($situationMaritale)
    {
        $this->situationMaritale = $situationMaritale;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get situationMaritale
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSituationMaritale()
    {
        return $this->situationMaritale;
    }

    /**
     * Set enfantsACharge
     *
     * @param integer $enfantsACharge
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setEnfantsACharge($enfantsACharge)
    {
        $this->enfantsACharge = $enfantsACharge;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get enfantsACharge
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getEnfantsACharge()
    {
        return $this->enfantsACharge;
    }




    /**
     * Set idSecu
     *
     * @param integer $idSecu
     * @return EgwContact
     */
    public function setIdSecu($idSecu)
    {
        $this->idSecu = $idSecu;

        return $this;
    }



    /**
     * Get idSecu
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getidSecu()
    {
        return $this->idSecu;
    }



    /**
     * Add typeContact
     *
     * @param Lea\PrestaBundle\Entity\EgwContact $typeContact
     * @return EgwContact


etc...
...

}
```

Comment: Sometimes you have this property private `$idSecu` as string and other is an integer. I dont know if this can help but what is happening when u do a `php bin/console cache:clear` ? the problem persist?
Or just erase your cache and vendor directory and make a composer update

Comment: Thanks Oscar : i 'll try but not convinced

Answer (score 1):

I FOUND ! in a Form calling the entity Ewg_contact linked to the entity Ewg_Categories, there was a hard parameter called: I replaced it with a variable. And it works.

This is by looking at the getProxy () function of the Doctrine class AbstractProxyFactory.php: there is an exception that calls the OutOfBoundsException :: missingPrimaryKeyValue function in which there is the message "

Missing value for primary key

Here is the correction made to the Form in question:

```
$param287=287;

$builder->add('categorie', EntityType::class, array(
        'class'     => 'LeaPrestaBundle:EgwCategories',
        'label'     => 'catName',
        'required'  => true,
        'empty_data' => null,
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er)
        {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->where('c.catParent = :parent')
        ->setParameter('parent',$param287 )
        ->orderBy('c.catName','ASC');
        },
    ));
```

EXPLANATION : Before it was :

```
->setParameter('parent', 287 )
```

witch provocated an exception in the getproxy function of AbstractProxyFactory.php class

Correct now
Thanks for your messages

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem. I found a possible "solution" in Doctrine Documentation. This one maybe can help.

i see in Documentation it's not possible to use not-primary key for joins columns.

Your column `id_ben` is a primary key ?

> It is not possible to use join columns pointing to non-primary keys. Doctrine will think these are the primary keys and create lazy-loading proxies with the data, which can lead to unexpected results. Doctrine can for performance reasons not validate the correctness of this settings at runtime but only through the Validate Schema command.

Comment: Hi Anthony, thanks for your answer : Yes "id_ben" is a primary key.

Comment: @glochenGUyirr ok, sorry for have disturbing you. I resolved my problem with this soluce, i was doing joins on not primary key. Good luck for resolving :)

Comment: no problem Biqette. I solved the problem but now i've got another problem and i 'm arraching my cheveux about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56666172/how-to-fix-missing-value-for-primary-key

Comment: @glochenGUyirr I cannot comment you new post, I do not have enough reputation points.
It's your conditions "where" in the var $sqlplus ? Show us the content please. It's not similar error at this post ?

Comment: It's probably a problem between 2 entities 

The link between entities egw_accounts and egw_addressbook is : ACCOUNT_ID

In the database, about the field ACCOUNT_ID there are exactly the same values in entities egw_accounts and egw_addressbook 
egw_accounts->ACCOUNT_ID = egw_addressbook->ACCOUNT_ID

SO, perhaps it's in the definition of entities that there's a problem

Remember that, i didnt have the problem in SYMFONY 2 : but in SYMFONY 3.4, the problem appears

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a problem between 2 entities

The link between entities egw_accounts and egw_addressbook is : ACCOUNT_ID

In the database, about the field ACCOUNT_ID there are exactly the same values in entities egw_accounts and egw_addressbook 
egw_accounts->ACCOUNT_ID = egw_addressbook->ACCOUNT_ID

SO, perhaps it's in the definition of entities that there's a problem

Remember that, i didnt have the problem in SYMFONY 2 : but in SYMFONY 3.4, the problem appears

THANKS for your help!

ENTITY EGW_ACCOUNTS

```
class EgwAccounts { /** * @var integer $accountId * * @ORM\Id * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY") * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="EgwAddressbook", cascade={"persist", "merge", "remove"}) * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="account_id", referencedColumnName="account_id") */ private $accountId;
```

With the SETTER :

```
`
/**
* Set accountId
*
* @param Lea\PrestaBundle\Entity\EgwAddressbook $accountId
* @return EgwAccounts
*/
public function setAccountId(\Lea\PrestaBundle\Entity\EgwAddressbook $accountId)
{
$this->accountId = $accountId;

    return $this;
}`
```

THE ENTITY EGW_ADDRESSBOOK

```
/** * @var integer $accountId * @ORM\Column(name="account_id", type="integer", nullable=true) */ private $accountId;
```